# Editing list view items dynamically when using cursor adapters and loaders

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I'm writing a tiny messaging app and I've recently encountered this problem.

I've got a `ListFragment` subclass, which implements a `CursorLoader` callback. The built-in `ListView` is bound to a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Every row view in this list has a level drawable as a background. I'd like to switch between the levels depending on the database info (whether the message was sent or not).

My question is how do you change *the background of a single row* in this case? Do I have to access it through the adapter? I'm pretty sure this should be done in the `onLoadFinished` method. But this code gives me `NullPointerException`. If you could point me in the right direction, I would be really grateful.

```
public class MessagesFragment extends ListFragment implements 
                              LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

private static MessagesFragment fragment;
private static MainActivity activity;
private static SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

public static MessagesFragment getInstance() {
    if (fragment == null)
        fragment = new MessagesFragment();

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(activity, R.layout.list_item, null,
            new String[] {DataProvider.KEY_NUMBER, DataProvider.KEY_MESSAGE, DataProvider.KEY_TIME},
            new int [] {R.id.item_field_number, R.id.item_field_message, R.id.item_field_time}, 0);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, null);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    activity.showDetails(Long.valueOf(id).intValue());
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(activity, DataProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    adapter.swapCursor(data);

    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        int id = data.getInt(data.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.KEY_ID));
        int sent = data.getInt(data.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.KEY_SENT));

        this.getListView().getChildAt(id).getBackground().setLevel(sent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you! Now my post looks way better. Wish I could upvote your edit :)

Comment: Where does the NullPointerException occur?

Comment: LogCat points at this line:
`this.getListView().getChildAt(id).getBackground().setLevel(sent);`

The values aren't empty. I've checked that.

Comment: What values aren't empty?  I would break that line out into separate lines for debugging, print the return value of each function.  If `id` and `sent` aren't null, then one of those functions is returning null during execution of the while-loop.  My money is on `getChildAt(id)`.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll try this now. Maybe the child view isn't instantiated when I call this method

Comment: Yep, the child view doesn't exist while the ListView does. I'll try to work something out. Thanks again, you've been a great help!

Comment: Try and implement your own SimpleCursorAdapter.  It'll take 2 minutes and you can do what you want a lot more cleanly and easily.

Comment: @bbaker Thanks a ton! It works perfectly. Really nice and simple. I guess I should learn more about the adapter and its lifecycle :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should Help!

```
public class SampleAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private Context context;

    public SampleAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[]            to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
        this.context = context;
        cursor = c;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cursor == null ? 0 : cursor.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
       return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (cursor != null) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            convertView.getBackground().setLevel(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.KEY_SENT)));
            holder.number.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.KEY_NUMBER)));
            holder.message.setText(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.KEY_MESSAGE)));
            holder.time.setText(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.KEY_TIME)));
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor c) {
        cursor = c;
        return super.swapCursor(c);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {

        TextView number;
        TextView message;
        TextView time;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_field_number);
            message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_field_message);
            time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_countries_time);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again! I heard the ViewHolder is more efficient. Perhaps I should use it. As soon as I get enough rep, I'll upvote your post ;)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I should've implemented the SimpleCursorAdapter instead of using the callback method. My gratitude goes to @bbaker :) Here's the code if someone's interested:

```
private class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int layout;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor,
            String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, from, to, flags);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.layout = layout;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return inflater.inflate(layout, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            TextView timeView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_field_time);
            int sent = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.KEY_SENT));
            timeView.getBackground().setLevel(sent);
        }
    }
}
```